# CSS - Can different images be uploaded based on device resolution?

Tags: css

We have images in different sizes for desktop, tablet and phone devices.
Can we tell browser what image to load using only CSS?

Can I use something like this?

```
<div class="image"></div>

<style>
  .image {background-image: url("/BIG/imageName.jpg");}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
     .image {background-image: url("/SMALL/imageName.jpg");}
  }
<style>
```

Will it load SMALL image if browser resolution will be 300px from start?

Thank you.

Comment: because you set that it should load SMALL image if it has MAX width 400?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set width and height for the image. Otherwise it will not show. Check my fiddle.

```
  .image {background-image: url("https://blogs.ubc.ca/CourseBlogSample01/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-1.jpg"); width:400px; height:300px;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .image {background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/t_demo_combined/sample.jpg"); width:100px; height:100px;}
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbL67/)

Answer (score 0):

This should

```
.image {background-image: url("/BIG/imageName.jpg");}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .image {background-image: url("/SMALL/imageName.jpg");}
}
```

Or (for readability):

```
@media (min-width: 401px) {
    .image {background-image: url("/BIG/imageName.jpg");}
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .image {background-image: url("/SMALL/imageName.jpg");}
}
```

Edit:

Oh, just one thing: Instead writing "only screen" I recommend to use https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond for older browser support.

Comment: Doesn't this load the BIG one also? (It will use the small one, but is the big one not loaded?)

Comment: You can simply check it using eg. Opera Dragonfly. Styles are updated after load entire block (or file) of code, so property have second value before browser start to load file. Edit: Of course you can use another `@media (min-width: 401px) {` for sure.

Comment: Yes, this was my primary concern - if both images will be loaded or not?

Comment: Browser will load just currently used one.